# How to search on two filed of a single object in nested field simultaneously in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a nested field in my elasticsearch. Imagine some data like this is stored on this field:

```
{
"id" : 1,
"students":[
     {"name": "John", "age": 20},{"name": "Alexander", "age":25},{"name": "Elizabeth", "age": 15}
    ]
},
"id" : 2,
"students":[
       {"name": "John", "age": 23},{"name": "Thomas", "age":30}
      ]
}
```

How can I query to get those documents which have student "John" and the his "age" is more than 21. If the query works well, the first document will not re retrieved as answer because "John" is 20 years old and we are looking for a "john" who is at least 21 years old. So, the second document must be retrieved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you provide your mapping or I can assume mapping myself, and provide solution accordingly ?

Comment: Please take yours! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a working example with index mapping,search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "students": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "students",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "students.name": "John" } },
            { "range": { "students.age": { "gt": 21 } } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64460956",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.8754687,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "students": [
            {
              "name": "John",
              "age": 23
            },
            {
              "name": "Thomas",
              "age": 30
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It works! But how it works?? why it did not match the first item? Does elasticsearch consider the same object which the first circumstance was right for it?

Comment: @saeednasehi glad this worked for you :) The nested query searches nested field objects as if they are indexed as separate documents. Therefore, here if the object matches both the condition in the `must` clause then only it will return the document.

Comment: @saeednasehi it will not match document 1, because of the condition on the `age` field (and the `must` clause. If you want to make a search such that, the query should match on either `name` field or `age` field then you can use `should` clause.

Comment: Oh! Thank you. I thought that elasticsearch check the first condition and second condition separately and two object in a document can be match with together.Really thanks!

Comment: @ESCoder is it possible to search for multiple nested.
let say I want to search document contain name: John, age: 23  AND name: Thomas, age: 30

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [nested query with inner_hits with source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits-source) to get the expected output in a better format.

Also please refer [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html#search-request-inner-hits) so that you can do advance operations on your query and search result.

**Index mapping, which includes the creation of `.keyword` fields so that you can retrieve the field-values for text fields**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "students": {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "age": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index your sample docs as you have in question and search query to retrieve the nested document**

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "students",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "students.name": "John"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "students.age": {
                                    "gt": 20
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "inner_hits": {
                "_source": false,
                "docvalue_fields": [
                    {
                        "field": "students.name.keyword",
                        "format": "use_field_mapping"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And inner-search result**

```
"inner_hits": {
                    "students": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 1,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 1.8754687,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "nestedstudent",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "2",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "students",
                                        "offset": 0
                                    },
                                    "_score": 1.8754687, // note this
                                    "fields": {
                                        "students.name.keyword": [
                                            "John"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: That is a great answer. Works for me! Thanks.

Comment: @saeednasehi thanks, please go through the links I provided which would be helpful for advance use-case.

Comment: @saeednasehi welcome, my fellow ES expert and friend 